# htaccess redirect to domain only if in specific directory match (not recursive)

Tags: .htaccess, directory, url-rewriting, conditional-statements, rule

I'm trying to accomplish such *RewriteCond* but I'm having problem with regex

REDIRECT to domain1.tld **ONLY IF** current address is domain2.tld/test/ but **NOT IF** domain2.com/test/_appz/

domain can be irrelevant:

REDIRECT to domain1.tld **ONLY IF** current address consists of directory /test/ but **NOT IF** in /test/_appz/ and deeper

I want to achieve conditions:

domain2.tld/test/       >>> redirect

domain2.tld/test/_appz/ >>> stay

otherdomain.tld         >>> stay

**EDIT:**

I'm writing own CMS for very own purposes, got 2 domains pointing to the same public_html,

one is official and one is used only to access via CMS.

```
cms.domain2.tld/test/ >>> redirect to domain1.com

cms.domain2.tld/test/_appz/ >>> no redirect

domain1.tld>>> no redirect (as it will be loop)
```

**domain1.tld** and **cms.domain2.tld** pointing to the same dir where **that .htaccess** exist

Thanks 4 your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either mod_alias or mod_rewrite to do redirection. Note that using mod_alias, you **don't** want to use the `Redirect` directive, which will virtually link two path nodes, this isn't what you want.

#### mod_alias

In the htaccess file in **domain2.tld**'s document root, add:

```
RedirectMatch ^/test/?$ http://domain1.tld/
```

If you want a permanent redirect:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test/?$ http://domain1.tld/
```

#### mod_rewrite

If you have rewrite rules that may interfere with mod_alias, then you may want to stick with just mod_rewrite. Also, if both the **domain1.tld** and **domain2.tld** share the same document root, you won't be able to use mod_alias. You'd want something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?test/?$ http://domain1.tld/ [L,R]
```

If you want a permanent redirect, change the flags to `[L,R=301]`.

Comment: Thanks Jon Li but that part `^/?test/?$`  doesn't work at all, if i put `^(.*)$` instead the redirect is working. I edited the Q for more explanation.